# How do I auth and remember a user from a dApp to a Laravel server using HTTP authentication?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, authentication, fedora

I'm trying to set up some routes for a Laravel API that receive and send data through a separate app. Right now, I have it communicating like this:

```
const request = require('request')

    const options = {url:'http://***.vagrant/signPersonal',headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}}
    request.post(options,function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(error,response,body)
      const signedData = '0x'+body.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
      console.log('sig: '+signedData.toString('hex'))
      callback(error, signedData)
    }).auth('****@**.*','123456123456',true).form(message)
```

Basically, I want to set up a login portal through the dApp (not the Laravel App) to authenticate the user for a certain amount of time. So how can I authenticate a user through routes, and time out their login session on the dApp.

Comment: on laravel side use passport to create oauth token and send it back to the app. then send the token with every http request from the app, on the laravel side use the authentication middleware to authenticate requests with token in the header.

Comment: I'm using no middleware right now, instead i created an /auth route to use the Auth::attempt login method with true as a parameter to remember user. However, when using Auth::viaRemember on another route, it always returns false. What kind of Auth middleware are you talking about? Auth or auth basic? I can grab the token, but I don't know how to authenticate with it.

Comment: to be clear, you have a laravel backend and a mobile app. the mobile app will do ajax calls to the laravel api right ?       if that is the case you have to use tokens, i personally use passport https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport, the documentation explain it all.

Comment: It's a Meteor web dApp, but close enough so I will give it a shot. Thank you!

Comment: So I still would prefer to use the default Auth system, as it makes it relatively simple to register/login and whatnot. I just need to be able to auth them for a short amount of time for security reasons.

Comment: oh i have no experience with Meteor... but if you are using laravel as an api only, the default auth system will not work since it cannot create sessions AFAIK. good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up just not using any middleware but instead creating a few custom functions for my own auth system. An auth route which updates the remember token through the normal auth request:

```
Route::get('/auth',function (Request $request){
    $email = $request->getUser();
    $password = $request->getPassword();
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password], true)) {
        User::updateRemembertoken(Auth::user(),Str::random(60));
        $token = Auth::getUser()['remember_token'];
        return response($token);
    }
});
```

This token is then saved on the app client-side and returned as an 'authorization' header to every other http call the app makes. I added this to User.php in the Laravel API:

```
    /**
     * Check to see if the "remember_me" token has been updated within the hour.
     *
     * @param  string  $date
     * @return bool
     */
    public static function tokenExpired($date){
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimeString($date);
        $currenttime = Carbon::now();
        $timePlushour = $date->addHour();
        if($currenttime->greaterThanOrEqualTo($timePlushour)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    /**
     * Update the "remember me" token for the given user in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable  $user
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public static function updateRememberToken(User $user, $token)
    {
        $user->remember_token = $token;
        //$user->setUpdatedAt(Carbon::now());
        $user->save();
    }

    public static function authUser(string $token){

        $findId = User::select('id')->where('remember_token',$token)->first();

        if($findId){
            if(Auth::loginUsingId($findId['id'])){
                $user = Auth::user()->all();
                if(User::tokenExpired(Auth::user()->updated_at)){
                    User::updateRemembertoken(Auth::user(),Str::random(60));
                }
                return Auth::user();
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It searches by the token and auths the user that way, but only if the token's been updated less than an hour prior.